# Receiving error on project build - "Error parsing XML: unbound prefix"

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android Development and trying to create a sample application. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with following layout (activity_sample.xml)? -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        tools:context=".SampleActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

On Build, I am getting following error -

```
error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix    activity_sample.xml /Sample/res/layout  line 4  Android AAPT Problem
```

Comment: `layout_centerHorizontal` and `layout_centerVertical` are members of RelativeLayout, they won't do anything for a LinearLayout. (Also if you are going to use both use `layout_centerInParent`.)

Comment: @Sam - +1 Very well. But how attributes of TextView are dependent on its parent container?

Comment: You can use `layout_gravity` in each child of a LinearLayout or `gravity` in the LinearLayout itself for all children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't declared the tools prefix in your XML. Try using:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        tools:context=".SampleActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```